# How to clone object record?

Tags: apex, lightning

Hi i have code for cloning selected record, but i need to do it without defining each field one by one.
Here is an example with 4 fields but in complete, there are almost 40 fields.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Claimed_Transaction__c> copyTransaction(String dataJson, String transId) {
    List<Claimed_Transaction__c> dataList = (List<Claimed_Transaction__c>) JSON.deserialize(dataJson, List<Claimed_Transaction__c>.class);

    Claimed_Transaction__c sourceTransaction = [SELECT Id FROM Claimed_Transaction__c WHERE Id=:transId];
    Claimed_Transaction__c targetTransaction = new Claimed_Transaction__c();

    targetTransaction.Name = sourceTransaction.Name;
    targetTransaction.Adress = sourceTransaction.Adress;
    targetTransaction.Phone = sourceTransaction.Phone ;
    targetTransaction.Temporary_Transaction__c = true;

    insert targetTransaction;
    dataList.add(targetTransaction);

    return dataList;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_clone):

> > clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps,
> > preserveAutonumber)
>
> Creates a copy of the SObject record.

So you can just do this:

```
Claimed_Transaction__c targetTransaction = sourceTransaction.clone(false,true,true,false);
```

Please read the documentation for more info on tweaking the function using the parameters it takes.

Answer (score 3):

you can Use clone Function to copy the selected record.Just to make code easier and not to mention the fields in code,you can use **fieldset** and retrieve those field in code.

PFB the sample code.

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>();
FieldSet fieldsToClone = SObjectType.Claimed_Transaction__c.fieldSets.FieldsToClone;
for (FieldSetMember field : fieldsToClone.getFields()) {
    fields.add(field.getFieldPath());
}
String soql = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ',') +
    ' FROM Claimed_Transaction__c WHERE Id = \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(transId) + '\'';
return Database.query(soql).Clone(...);
```

This is sample code.please change it according to your functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the clone method from SObject class. 
Make sure your source object has all the fields queried. So if you have queried 4 fields then it will populate those fields only in the cloned object.

```
Claimed_Transaction__c claimedTransaction = [SELECT Id FROM Claimed_Transaction__c WHERE Id=:transId];
Claimed_Transaction__c clonedClaimedTransaction = claimedTransaction.clone(false, false, false, false);
```

To query all the fields you can run a [Dynamic SOQL Query for all fields](https://sfcure.com/2018/03/15/salesforce-cookies-10/)